# How to pass the particular parameter in blob.upload function of python aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, assume-role

```
def connection_to_another_acc():
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::account-of-role-to-assume:role/name-of-role",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )
    credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    s3_resource=boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    file_path="xyz"
    s3_path= "abx"
    bucket= "name"
    upload_to_s3(s3_resource,file_path, s3_path, bucket)

def upload_to_s3(s3_resource,file_path, s3_path, bucket):
    ### s3_resource (where to pass this params)
    response = blob.upload_file(file_path, bucket, s3_path)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)
        info("Removed the file from tmp directory")
    else:
        info("File not found")

    return response

connection_to_another_acc()
```

#### My doubt how to pass the s3_resource in blob.upload or is there any different way to upload the files from one account to another account? Please guide me.

Comment: Take the reference of this one. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Comment: I’m a bit confused by your question, are you asking how to move objects between S3 buckets located in two different accounts? If so, consider the copy_object command. Happy to explain in more depth if relevant

Comment: @mkamioner
, Could you please guide me in detail? I am trying to upload files in two AWS accounts. one is mine and in my client aws account

Comment: @Mia - sorry for the delayed response. See the copy_object command (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) -- You can upload as normal account A, then using a role that has read access from A and write access to B will allow you to copy the file into B without having to reupload.